# Laravel Web Push notification using edujugon push-notification

Tags: android, ios, laravel, push-notification, web-push

I have a problem in my project. I am using edujugon push-notification for push notification of my app, I created push notification to android, ios devices successfully with title, body. But when I integrate the notification in my web devices it does not show the title and body rather it shows `the site is upgrated in backend`. Also I want to set an url in my web notification. But dont know how.

Here is my code

```
public static function sendPushNotification($devices, $pushData, $partner = false) {

    $android = $devices->where('type', 2)->pluck('token')->all();
    if (!empty($android)) {
        $push = new PushNotification('fcm');

        $push->setMessage(
            [
                'data' => $pushData,
            ]
        )
            ->setDevicesToken($android)
            ->send();
    }

    $ios = $devices->where('type', 1)->pluck('token')->all();

    if (!empty($ios)) {
        $push = new PushNotification('apn');

        $feedback = $push->setMessage(
                [
                    'aps' => [
                        'alert' => [
                            'title' => $pushData['title'],
                            'body' => $pushData['body'],
                        ],
                        'sound' => 'default',
                        'badge' => 1
                    ],
                    'data' => $pushData
                ]
        )->setDevicesToken($ios)->send()->getFeedback();
    }

    $web = $devices->where('type', 3)->pluck('token')->all();
    if (!empty($web)) {
        $push = new PushNotification('fcm');

        $push->setMessage($pushData)->setDevicesToken($web)->send();
    }
}
```

and my push data is

```
$pushData = [
    'title' => 'Test',
    'body' => 'Test',
];
```

Please help me solving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this

```
if (!empty($web)) {
            $push = new PushNotification('fcm');

            $push->setMessage(
                [
                    'notification' => $pushData,
                ]
            )->setDevicesToken($web)->send();
        }
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.